# CGPoint Run-Time Error iOS Swift

Tags: swift, cgpoint

I'm receiving a run-time error on the following statement inside of my `ViewController` class.  This seems so straightforward, but tons of searching and videos later, I can't figure out what I did wrong.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Main image view controller
    @IBOutlet var drawing_ImageView: UIImageView!

    // store a point coordinate value based on screen touch
    var start = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)  
}
```

The `var start = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)` line throws the error.  I also tried:

```
var start: CGPoint
```

but that also throws an error.  What am I missing?  No build or compile errors are thrown.

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

Comment: It works for me in a playground.   Do you have a more detailed exception?  Maybe it has to do with the storyboard.  Also FYI CGPoint has a zero property: CGPoint.zero

Comment: I don't have any more detail on the exception.  Any ideas on what storyboard issue could cause this?  I have UIKit (and CoreGraphics) imported.

Comment: I started from a new storyboard and just copied all of the files back in.  It works now... I'm still not sure what happened.  I'm using the exact same code.   Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Create an exception breakpoint to isolate the error. Sometimes quitting Xcode and clearing the DerivedData folder and opening Xcode helps.